# Device not ready when sending http post with X509 Certificate

Tags: vb.net, ssl, http-post, x509certificate

I have a windows application that makes a HTTP post to send and receive some XML. On a Windows PC it works, but since moving it to the test server (Windows 2008 r2) I am getting "*Device not Ready*" error when loading the certificate.

The error is a bit vague, and obviously searches are some quite vague results. Has anyone come across this? The code breaks at Dim Certificate....

The certificate is installed and exportable. Be grateful for any suggestions.

```
Dim SendPropertyUri As String = "http://post.url"
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
Dim byteData() As Byte
Dim postStream As Stream = Nothing
request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(SendPropertyUri), HttpWebRequest)
Dim certificate As New X509Certificate("D:\Processor\certificates\mycert.p12", "password")
request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate)
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/xml"
request.Accept = "application/xml"
byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(foo.OuterXml)
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length
postStream = request.GetRequestStream()
postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
postStream.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research this problem was resolved by installing IIS6 compatibility components. Unsure as to exactly what was causing the problem but after installing IIS6 Management console it worked without issue.

Just answering as the error is a vague one so may help someone else or give them a starting point.